# Testcafe-Saucelab integration issue

Tags: testing, browser, automated-tests, testcafe, saucelabs

I get the below error when running the command `testcafe -b saucelabs`:

```
ERROR Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 54.192.148.204:443
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1097:14)
```

Can someone please help me with resolving this?

Comment: testcafe-browser-provider-saucelabs fetches information about available configurations from https://wiki-assets.saucelabs.com/ Is it reachable from your machine?

Comment: Im getting the below error       <Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>0B83DDAE20A996D1</RequestId>
<HostId>
vpB1Hkbj93SskT37IY/G/S92A4jGCbwXZ4KNAgtoUBltMoC2exJIh+WFK4AP1c+HU5kU68FSND0=
</HostId>
</Error>

Comment: Could you please try to navigate to the direct url of the asset data: https://wiki-assets.saucelabs.com/data/selenium_pc_windows-10.1576110946.json ? It should return a list of available browsers.

Comment: Yes, im able to navigate to : https://wiki-assets.saucelabs.com/data/selenium_pc_windows-10.1576110946.json.  Listed the browsers available.

Comment: Try to debug the problem on your machine. Install the latest version of the 'testcafe-browser-provider-saucelabs' module, add the 'console.error(e)' statement in the [catch](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe-browser-provider-saucelabs/blob/master/src/index.js#L61) block, run the 'testcafe -b saucelabs' command in your terminal and provide the command execution result.